# Using terms in NativeQuery to search for multiple optional matches

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

The elasticsearch document has "flattened" fields that can contain one or more pairs of "name":"value".
For example, the "flattened" fields "genre" and "countries" look like this:
"genres": [
{
"uuidGenre": "28e71bf4-21cd-49c0-a0ca-4913b4b50d86",
"genreName": "Comedy"
},
{
"uuidGenre": "fe6b5d15-bf73-4b34-a02e-13d110c89a3f",
"genreName": "Fantastic"
}

```
 "countries": [
        {
            "uuidCountry": "ee88f16d-8492-42d8-8dff-3cd0f10d7121",
            "countryName": "Can"
        },
        {
            "uuidCountry": "ee88f16d-0987-42d8-8dff-3cd0f10d7121",
            "countryName": "India"
        }
```

To search for a document, a query may contain one or more selection criteria for such "flattened" fields.
For example, for selection by the "genres" field, the request may contain only one "uuidGenre" value,
and for the "countries" field, there may be more than one "uuidCountry" value.
Thus, the selection should include documents that match at least one criterion of the request.
But if the criterion for strict compliance is applied - "age":"18+", then only documents with the criterion "age": "18+" should get into the selection,
which partially or completely meet the criteria for "uuidGenre" and "uuidCountry".
Such a request directly to the index in Postman looks like this:

```
{ "query":{
"bool":{ 
  "must":[
    {"match":{"age":18}},
    {"bool":{
      "should":[
        { "terms":
           { "genres.uuidGenre": ["c6bee588-3b47-4307-ba00-40764d50a57a", "fe6b5d15-bf73-4b34-a02e-13d110c89a3f"] } },
        { "terms": { "countries.uuidCountry": ["24cb3786-d85c-418c-af90-c719c2a5a796" , "ee88f16d-8492-42d8-8dff-3cd0f10d7121"] } }
        ] 
      }
    } 
  ]
}}}
```

and it gives the expected result.
To create an API in java, I use Query filmQuery = NativeQuery.builder(). The request looks like this:

```
 Query filmQuery = NativeQuery.builder()
        .withQuery(q1 -> q1
                .bool(bq -> {
                    if (titleInLowercase.equals("")) {
                        bq.must(ma -> ma.matchAll(m -> m));
                        sortParam.set(Sort.by("title.keyword").ascending());
                    } else if ((titleInLowercase.length()) == 1) {
                        bq.must(m -> m.prefix(p -> p
                                .field("title")
                                .value(titleInLowercase))
                        );
                        sortParam.set(Sort.by("title.keyword").descending());
                    } else if ((titleInLowercase.length()) >= 2) {
                        bq.must(m -> m.match(ma -> ma
                                .field("title")
                                .query(titleInLowercase)
                        ));
                        sortParam.set(Sort.by("title.keyword").ascending());
                    }
                    if (!frontRequest.isNull("genres") && finalValueListGenres.size() > 1) {
                        for (Object uuid : finalValueListGenres) {
                            bq.should(m -> m
                                    .term(t -> t
                                            .field("genres.uuidGenre")
                                            .value(String.valueOf(uuid))
                                    ));
                        }
                    }
                    if (!frontRequest.isNull("countries") && finalValueListCountries.size() > 1) {
                        for (Object uuid : finalValueListCountries) {
                            bq.should(m -> m
                                    .term(t -> t
                                            .field("countries.uuidCountry")
                                            .value(String.valueOf(uuid))
                                    ));
                        }
                    }
                    if (!frontRequest.isNull("language") && finalValueListLanguage.size() > 1) {
                        for (Object uuid : finalValueListLanguage) {
                            bq.should(m -> m
                                    .term(t -> t
                                            .field("language_id.uuidLanguage")
                                            .value(String.valueOf(uuid))
                                    ));
                        }
                    }
                    bq.minimumShouldMatch("3");
                    return bq;
                }))
        .withFilter(f -> f
                .bool(b -> {
                            if (!frontRequest.isNull("language") && finalValueListLanguage.size() == 1) {
                                for (Object uuid : finalValueListLanguage) {
                                    b.must(fbm -> fbm
                                            .term(t -> t
                                                    .field("language_id.uuidLanguage")
                                                    .value(String.valueOf(uuid))));
                                }
                            }
                            if (!frontRequest.isNull("genres") && finalValueListGenres.size() == 1) {
                                b.must(bm -> bm
                                        .term(t -> t
                                                .field("genres.uuidGenre")
                                                .value(String.valueOf(finalValueListGenres.get(0)))));
                            }
                            if (!frontRequest.isNull("countries") && finalValueListCountries.size() == 1) {
                                for (Object uuid : finalValueListCountries) {
                                    b.must(m -> m
                                            .term(ma -> ma
                                                    .field("countries.uuidCountry")
                                                    .value(String.valueOf(uuid))));
                                }
                            }
                            if (!frontRequest.isNull("age")) {
                                b.filter(m -> m
                                        .term(t -> {
                                            try {
                                                return t
                                                        .field("age")
                                                        .value(frontRequest.getInt("age"));
                                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                throw new RuntimeException(e);
                                            }
                                        }));
                            }
                            if (!frontRequest.isNull("is_popular")) {
                                b.filter(m -> m
                                        .term(t -> {
                                            try {
                                                return t
                                                        .field("is_popular")
                                                        .value(frontRequest.getBoolean("is_popular"));
                                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                throw new RuntimeException(e);
                                            }
                                        }));
                            }
                            if (!frontRequest.isNull("is_new")) {
                                b.filter(m -> m
                                        .term(t -> {
                                            try {
                                                return t
                                                        .field("is_new")
                                                        .value(frontRequest.getBoolean("is_new"));
                                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                throw new RuntimeException(e);
                                            }
                                        }));
                            }
                            if (!frontRequest.isNull("type")) {
                                b.filter(m -> m
                                        .term(t -> {
                                            try {
                                                return t
                                                        .field("mediaTypeId")
                                                        .value(frontRequest.getInt("type"));
                                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                throw new RuntimeException(e);
                                            }
                                        }));
                            }
                            if (!frontRequest.isNull("years")) {
                                for (String years : finalYearsList) {
                                    String yearsOfReleaseDate = String.valueOf(years);
                                    java.time.LocalDate beginningDate = java.time.LocalDate.parse(yearsOfReleaseDate + "-01-01");
                                    java.time.LocalDate beginningDatePlusYear = beginningDate.plusYears(1);

                                    JsonData jsonBeginningDate = JsonData.of(String.valueOf(beginningDate));
                                    JsonData jsonBeginningDatePlusYear = JsonData.of(String.valueOf(beginningDatePlusYear));
                                    b.filter(m -> m
                                            .range(ma -> ma
                                                    .field("release_date")
                                                    .gte(jsonBeginningDate)
                                                    .lt(jsonBeginningDatePlusYear)
                                            )
                                    );
                                }
                            }
                            return b;
                        }
                ))
        .withSort(sortParam.get())
        .withPageable(Pageable.ofSize(pageSize))
        .build();
```

I can't find a way to use "terms" in a Query query...
I would appreciate the help of a novice javist

Answer (score 0):

your are already using a `term` query, for example

```
 bq.should(m -> m
     .term(t -> t
       .field("countries.uuidCountry")
       .value(String.valueOf(uuid))
    ));
```

the query builder has a `terms()` method as well

Comment: yes, I seem to understand the use of "term", but this is not enough for the desired result, and I can't find a way to apply "terms".
After studying the methods/constructors that offer the Query, Terms Query, Terms Query Field classes, it did not become clearer.
I would be grateful for an example of using "terms" in the query code using Query queryTerms = NativeQuery.builder()
                .withQuery(q -> q.bool(b -> {...

Comment: Please read what I wrote. There is `term()` (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-java/blob/main/java-client/src/main/java/co/elastic/clients/elasticsearch/_types/query_dsl/Query.java#L1095-L1098) and there is `terms()` (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-java/blob/main/java-client/src/main/java/co/elastic/clients/elasticsearch/_types/query_dsl/Query.java#L1112-L1114)

Answer (score 0):

After getting acquainted with the specifications of the Field Value, TermsQueryField and TermsQuery classes, such a solution appeared:

```
 Query filmQuery = NativeQuery.builder()
            .withQuery(q -> q.bool(b -> {
                if (titleInLowercase.equals("")) {
                b.must/term/should...}
                b.filter(m -> m.bool(mb -> {
                    if (!frontRequest.isNull("countries") && finalValueListCountries.size() > 1) {
                        System.out.println("valueListCountries.size() > 1 ");
                        List<FieldValue> fieldValueList = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (String uuid :
                                finalValueListCountries) {
                            FieldValue.Builder fieldValueBuilder = new FieldValue.Builder();
                            fieldValueBuilder.stringValue(uuid);
                            FieldValue fieldValue = fieldValueBuilder.build();
                            fieldValueList.add(fieldValue);
                        }
                        TermsQueryField termsQueryField = new TermsQueryField.Builder()
                                .value(fieldValueList)
                                .build();
                        mb.filter(s -> s
                                .terms(t -> t
                                        .field("countries.uuidCountry")
                                        .terms(termsQueryField)));
                    }
```

I would be grateful for the recommendations, if it's not about abandoning my idea to learn java